# What is this mount with two buttons on side of Vivitar 75-205mm lens?

Tags: lens-mount, old-lenses

I recently acquired this lens, but I cannot figure out the exact mount on the lens, does anyone know? I was told by the seller that it was for a Nikon camera. However, this mount looks nothing like the Nikon mount with the Rabbit ears.

[image: Vivitar Mount 1]
[image: Vivitar Mount 2]
[image: Vivitar Mount 3]

Comment: When asking lens identification questions, it's helpful to identify all the engraved lettering on and around the lens.

Comment: Lens is made by Kiron. I had a copy with a Nikon mount. It was pretty sharp, but got rid of it because I prefer another lens that covers the same focal length. Here's a [photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09ZSK.jpg) that was taken with it. (I agree with [scottbb](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/109179/75526), your copy has OM mount.)

Answer (score 6):

I believe this is an Olympus OM mount lens. The lens release button and aperture stop-down button opposing each other are a dead giveaway. Also, unless I'm mistaken, the engraved lettering in the first picture says something like "for O/OM"... ?

Comment: You are absolutely correct @scottbb. It was right in front of my face and I didn't even realize it. thank you so much!